# Change Return-Path address with postfix/opendkim

Tags: centos, postfix, opendkim

I've just set up opendkim on my server. Prior to this I had postfix set up to have the return path headers set to `info@domain.com` now after installing opendkim that's now changed back to what it was before I made the postfix change to `apache@www.domain.com`

```
Return-Path: <apache@www.domain.com>
Received: from www.domain.com ([xx.xx.xx.xx])
        by mx.google.com with SMTP id y2si1560966wja.78.2015.12.23.02.39.47
        for <me@domain.com>;
        Wed, 23 Dec 2015 02:39:48 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of apache@www.domain.com designates xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender) client-ip=xx.xx.xx.xx;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of apache@www.domain.com designates xx.xx.xx.xx as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=apache@www.domain.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@domain.com
```

Why did this change after installing opendkim and how can I change it now?

For reference, my original modifications that worked before using dkim were as follows:

1. add the line `smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`
2. add the line `apache@www.domain.com  info@domain.com` in /etc/postfix/generic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why, when or how this happened, but I noticed a few lines like this in my **maillog**;

```
warning: database /etc/postfix/generic.db is older than source file /etc/postfix/generic
```

So in trying to fix that warning I found something to tell me to run;

```
postmap /etc/postfix/generic
```

Which appeared to suppress these errors, but it has also fixed my headers back to what they should be. All sorted now.